# Утечка памяти в ffmpeg при записи с IP-камеры

Tags: утечка-памяти, видео, ffmpeg, c++

Всем доброго времени суток!
Утекает память в ffmpeg, сделал тестовую программу, которая каждые 30 секунд запускает новый поток, записывающий видео с IP-камеры. Прошу помощи в локализации, где утекает, и как с этим бороться.

Код тестовой программы [здесь](https://github.com/xaruch/ffmpeg_tests).

Comment: Попробуйте тулзы, которые дают эту информацию, вроде dr.memory для linux или memory leak detector для vc. Кроме того, Intel Studio дает прекрасный набор утилит для детекта таких проблем.